# Is there a way to store a value persistently without using a variable with global or module scope in c?

Tags: c

For example, if I write a ftn called `"add"` that consumes a int `"a"` and produce a value of `a + b`, `b` is a value that is produced by the last called.
    eg

```
add(1) ==> 1 (first called b=0,then 1 + 0 = 1)
add(2) ==> 3 (second called b=1, then 2 + 1 = 3)
add(4) ==> 7 (third called b=3, then 3 + 4 =7)
```

EDIT: even without using "static"

Comment: How about a static local variable?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the static keyword in front of your variable inside the function?

Comment: Isn't "static" a module scope?

Comment: @IMPERFECT module **?**, There is four things: (1) local static variable scope is local to the function it is declared (e.g. below in `add()` function), so all are different, (2) but there life is till you program not terminates. (3) All have initial value (default) 0. and (4) memory from static segment.

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway? If you want the program to remember the value from a previous function call, the value has to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why without static? It's exactly what you need, isn't it?
Otherwise, you can pass a parameter as a pointer and change it anywhere you want.

```
void f( int * a )
{
    *a += 5;
}
```

and in main, or wherever you call

```
int a = 0;
f( &a );
f( &a );
```

`a` will be 10 and you can also work with it in function.

Is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you. For this question, I just out of curiosity. :)

Comment: `void add( int * a, int value )
{
    *a += value;
    printf( "%d\n", *a );
}`

And call
`int a = 0; add( &a, somevalue );`

Answer (score 2):

Will this do what you want?

```
int add(int a) {
  static int b = 0;
  return b += a;
}
```

The static variable `b` is local to the `add()` function but keeps its value between calls.

Comment: Even without static, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

How about a static local variable?

```
int add(int a)
{
    static int b = 0;
    b += a;
    return b;
}
```

or maybe a lambda:

```
int main(int,char**)
{
    int b = 0;
    auto add = [&](int a) { b += a; return b; };
    std::cout << add(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << add(2) << "\n";
    std::cout << add(4) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
1
3
7
```

Comment: Even without static, do you have any idea?

Comment: @IMPERFECT read Michal Bukovy's solution using pass by address (pointer).

Comment: @IMPERFECT: I've added an example using a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int test1(){
    static int localVar=0;
    localVar++;
    printf("test1 %i\n",localVar);
}

int test2(){
    static int localVar=0;
    localVar++;
    printf("test2 %i\n",localVar);
}

int main(){
    test1();
    test2();
    test1();
}
```

Running this prints

```
test1 1
test2 1
test1 2
```

because static applies to the variable in the scope in which it is defined, in this case, both inside test1 and inside test2, both start with a value of 0 and increment each time the function is called, as you can see, even after the first call to test1, the value inside test2 has not incremented.  Calling test1 again shows that the value is remembered.  If you're not convinced, adjust the number of times each is called and try it yourself.

Comment: just for good form's sake I would also initialise those localvars to zero.

Comment: Good point, GCC takes care of you pretty reliably but there is no gaurantee of that, I'll fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain state, but you don't want the function to store it in a `static` variable, there are limited options.

You could just pass the state in, eg:

```
/* Be careful with the first call - the caller must initialise
   previous_result to 0 */
int add(int a, int *prev_result)
{
    int result = a + *prev_result;
    *prev_result = result;
    return result;
}
```

Or, you could store it in a file, eg:

```
/* Incomplete, and completely untested! */
int add(int a)
{
    FILE *state_file;
    int result
    int prev_result;

    state_file = fopen("state.txt", "r");
    prev_result = get_value_from_file(state_file);  /* write this yourself */
    fclose(state_file);

    result = a + prev_result;

    state_file = fopen("state.txt", "w");
    write_value_to_file(state_file, result);   /* write this yourself */
    fclose(state_file);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int value){
    FILE *fp;
    int pv = 0;

    fp = fopen("temp.bin", "r+b");
    if(fp==NULL){
        fp = fopen("temp.bin", "wb+");
        fwrite(&pv, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        rewind(fp);
    }
    fread(&pv, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    pv += value;
    rewind(fp);
    fwrite(&pv, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return pv;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", add(1));
    printf("%d\n", add(2));
    printf("%d\n", add(4));
    return 0;
}
```